# Postgresql update a table with join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I need to update a Table using information from other table.
This is my sql query:

```
UPDATE service a 
JOIN agency b USING (feed_id) 
SET end_date = (SELECT MIN(start_date)-1 
                FROM service c 
                JOIN agency d USING (feed_id) 
                WHERE b.feed_id = a.feed_+1 
                      AND b.agency_id = d.agency_id)
```

I need agency id in the condition so the only way is join both table with agency table.

Postgres return:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "JOIN"
LINE 1: UPDATE service a JOIN agency b USING (feed_id) SET end_date ...
```

Any tips?

Comment: "*doesn't work*" is not a valid Postgres error message. Where [**in the manual**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html) did you find that syntax?

Comment: Please [edit] your question add the `create table` statements for the tables in question, some sample data and the expected result based on that data. [**Formatted**](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

```
UPDATE service
SET end_date = (SELECT MIN(start_date)-1 
                FROM service c 
                JOIN agency d USING (feed_id) 
                WHERE b.feed_id = a.feed_+1 
                      AND b.agency_id = d.agency_id)
FROM service a
JOIN agency b USING (feed_id)
```

Comment: Do **not** repeat the target table in the `FROM`clause of an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: i take `syntax error at or near "JOIN"` if i doesn't

Comment: Doesn't work. It's better add second join in the subquery

Answer (score 0):

This query works:

```
UPDATE service a
SET end_date = (SELECT MIN(start_date)-1
            FROM service b
            JOIN agency c ON b.feed_id = c.feed_id
            JOIN agency d ON a.feed_id = d.feed_id 
            WHERE b.feed_id = a.feed_id+1 
            AND c.agency_id = d.agency_id
            )
```